# Can I get absolute URI of video on camera roll and mutate it from my app?

Tags: ios, swift, image, video, camera-roll

I want to perform an operation on a video in the iphone camera roll, and I require an absolute URI as I will be using ffmpeg natively within my app.

Is it possible to operate on the video in place? or would I need to copy the video to a tmp dir, operate on it, and then write back to the camera roll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've read some docs and tutorials and answering below based on that research.

**Is it possible to operate on the video in place?**

> Yes (By copying it to temp dir) and No (to the original location where the video is actually stored)

Take a look at the following image and quote from [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit)

[image]

> Using PhotoKit, you can **fetch and cache** assets for display and
>   playback, edit image and video content or manage collections of
>   assets such as albums, Moments, and Shared Albums.

We don't have direct access to the location where the image/video is stored instead we get raw data or representation using [PHAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset) and Asset objects are immutable so we can't perform operations directly on it. We would need [PHAssetChangeRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest) to create, delete, change the metadata for, or edit the content of a Photos asset.

**would I need to copy the video to a temp dir, operate on it, and then write back to the camera roll?**

> Yep, that's the way to go.

Comment: Of course a user can edit an image/video in place, the user will just be prompted with an alert telling them to confirm the changes. See the PHAsset class.

Comment: @K4747Z Agreed. But with that, I meant directly to original location where the Video is actually stored.

Comment: But if we try to replace the edited video , when time of deleting un-edited video it will ask the permission to delete from `photos` , right ?......which may look odd, don't you think that ??

Comment: @NayanDave we don't need to delete the original video. if you look at the PHAssetChangeRequest class they have mentioned "edit the content of Photos asset" and this is our case: edit the video. so the user will be prompted only once.

Answer (score 3):

**If you already fetched the assets, and have the PHFetchResult object try:**

```
var video = PHAsset() // the video to be edited
```

…

```
 if video.canPerform(.content) {  // check if the selected PHAsset can be edited

  video.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { editingInput, _ in

  let videoAsset = editingInput?.audiovisualAsset // get tracks and metadata of the video and start editing
  let videoURL = (videoAsset as? AVURLAsset)?.url // This might be nil so better use videoAsset

        /*
         Start editing your video here


        */

  guard let input = editingInput else { return }
  let output = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: input)
  let outputURL = output.renderedContentURL // URL at which you write/export the edited video, it must be a .mov file
  let editedVideo = NSData()  // suppose your video fileName is editedVideo.mov, I used NSData since I don't know what final edited object will be.
  editedVideo.write(to: outputURL, atomically: false)

  PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
  let changeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest(for: video)
  changeRequest.contentEditingOutput = output
               })
            })

        }
```

**Or if you're using default imagePicker, we can get tmp video url using:**

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! NSURL
    print(videoURL)  // file is already in tmp folder


     let video = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as! PHAsset
        // implement the above code using this PHAsset 

   // your will still need to request photo library changes, and save the edited video and/or delete the older one

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement something like this in my project I hope it will help you.

I show all the items in collection view and perform action on selection , you can also get the url of selected video

```
func getVideoFromCameraRoll() {
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false) ]
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
    videos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
    videoLibraryCV.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return videos.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let asset = videos!.object(at: indexPath.row)
    let width: CGFloat = 150
    let height: CGFloat = 150
    let size = CGSize(width:width, height:height)
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit, options: nil)
    {   (image, userInfo) -> Void in

        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = image

        let labelView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        labelView.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d",Int((asset.duration / 60)),Int(asset.duration) % 60)
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
 let asset = photos!.object(at: indexPath.row)
 guard(asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.Video)
 else {
  print("Not a valid video media type")
  return
 }

 PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {
  (asset: AVAsset ? , audioMix : AVAudioMix ? , info : [NSObject: AnyObject] ? ) in
  let asset = asset as!AVURLAsset
  print(asset.URL) // Here is video URL
 })

}
```

I hope it will work for you ...:)